# Unique values for the 1st group then the 1st and 2nd and so on

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 different groups :

```
   id group
1  L1     1
2  L2     1
3  L1     2
4  L3     2
5  L4     2
6  L3     3
7  L5     3
8  L6     3
9  L1     4
10 L4     4
11 L2     5
```

I would like to know if it's possible to get the unique `id` from the 1st group, the 1st and the 2nd, the 1st, 2nd and 3rd and so on without for looping. I'm searching a way with `dplyr` or `data.table` package.

Expected results :

```
    group      id
1   1          c("L1", "L2")
2   1,2        c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4")
3   1,2,3      c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5")
4   1,2,3,4    c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5")
5   1,2,3,4,5  c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5")
```

Data :

```
structure(list(id = c("L1", "L2", "L1", "L3", "L4", "L3", "L5", 
"L6", "L1", "L4", "L2"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With base R, you can do:

```
# create the "growing" sets of groups
combi_groups <- lapply(seq_along(unique(df$group)), function(i) unique(df$group)[1:i])

# get the unique ID for each set of groups
uniq_ID <- setNames(lapply(combi_groups, function(x) unique(df$id[df$group %in% x])), 
                    sapply(combi_groups, paste, collapse=","))

# $`1`
# [1] "L1" "L2"

# $`1,2`
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4"

# $`1,2,3`
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"

# $`1,2,3,4`
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"

# $`1,2,3,4,5`
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"
```

If you want to format as in your expected output:

```
data.frame(group=sapply(combi_groups, paste, collapse=", "), id=sapply(uniq_ID, function(x) paste0("c(", paste0("\"", x, "\"", collapse=", "), ")")))
#          group                                    id
#1             1                         c("L1", "L2")
#2          1, 2             c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4")
#3       1, 2, 3 c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6")
#4    1, 2, 3, 4 c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6")
#5 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6")
```

Another possibility of formatting:

```
data.frame(group=rep(names(uniq_ID), sapply(uniq_ID, length)), id=unlist(uniq_ID))
```

Or, if you want to have `uniq_ID` in a column:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(group=sapply(combi_groups, paste, collapse=", "), id=uniq_ID)
#           group                id
#1:             1             L1,L2
#2:          1, 2       L1,L2,L3,L4
#3:       1, 2, 3 L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6
#4:    1, 2, 3, 4 L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6
#5: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6

data.table(group=sapply(combi_groups, paste, collapse=", "), id=uniq_ID)[2, id]
[[1]]
[1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4"
```

Comment: @Cath Thanks a lot ! "However" the results in the col `id` are not easy to work on. I should have mentioned it but I was expecting a vector for each row (that's why I wrote this syntax but I think it was a bit confusing) because, atm, I can't use basic functions such as `length()`, `setdiff()` since they are factors.

Comment: @Omlere then you can work with `uniq_ID`, last part of my answer was only to format the result

Comment: @Cath And it's possible to convert `uniq_id` in a dataframe with one column and each row is an element of the list ?

Comment: @Omlere as in `unlist(uniq_ID)` ? or `data.frame(group=rep(names(uniq_ID), sapply(uniq_ID, length)), id=unlist(uniq_ID))` ?

Comment: @Cath as in my expected results, each row is the "main" element of the list `uniq_ID` so the dataframe would have 5 rows and in the first row, it would contain `c("L1", "L2)`, 2nd row `c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4")`. Basically something that can do this : `df[i,"id"] <- uniq_ID[i]`

Comment: @Omlere you will then need to put it in another format as you cannot have a list with different lengths in a data.frame. I edited with an option in a `data.table`

Answer (score 6):

In similar vein as the answer of @Cath, but using `Reduce(..., accumulate = TRUE)` to create the expanding window of groups. Then loop over the set of groups with `lapply` to get the unique id's for each window:

```
grp <- Reduce(c, unique(d$group), accumulate = TRUE)

lapply(grp, function(x) unique(d$id[d$group %in% x]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "L1" "L2"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"
```

---

For naming and prettification, please refer to the nice answer by @Cath.

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to use `split` and `Reduce` to feed the groups to `union` with accumulate=TRUE:

```
Reduce(union, split(df$id, df$group), accumulate=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "L1" "L2"

[[2]]
[1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4"

[[3]]
[1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"

[[4]]
[1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"

[[5]]
[1] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "L6"
```

Comment: Nice indeed! I really wish I could squeeze in another upvote.